# Plotting multiple plots on the same page using ggplot and for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have several dataframes that I have called and placed within a list as follows:

```
plots_list <- list(data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5)
```

I have defined a function, which takes in data from each dataframe and plots the residuals:

```
residual_plots <- function(data) {
  ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point(
      aes(color = col1,
          shape = col2),
      na.rm = T,
      size = 1.2
    ) +
    geom_hline(
      yintercept = 0,
      colour = "dimgray",
      linetype = "solid",
      size = 0.25
    ) +
    geom_abline(
      intercept = 0,
      slope = 0.1,
      colour = "dimgray",
      linetype = "dashed",
      size = 0.25
    ) +
    geom_abline(
      intercept = 0,
      slope = -0.1,
      colour = "dimgray",
      linetype = "dashed",
      size = 0.25
    )                   
}
```

Since I have multiple dataframes, I wanted to use a for-loop to get the job done quickly. This is the code I have used:

```
res_plot_list <- vector("list", length = length(plots_list))
```

```
for (i in (plots_list)) {
  res_plot_list[[i]] <- residual_plots(i)
}
```

```
ml <- marrangeGrob(res_plot_list, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
ml
```

I have tried multiple variations to try and get all the plots onto the same page but I keep hitting some form of dead end. As of now, when I use this code, I keep running into the following error:

```
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = residual_plots(i)) : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I would really appreciate any help on how I can best approach this problem, because I am unable to find the right one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` in the `for` loop is the dataset hence `res_plot_list[[i]]` fails. Try -

```
for (i in seq_along(plots_list)) {
  res_plot_list[[i]] <- residual_plots(plots_list[[i]])
}
```

Or why not just use `lapply` -

```
res_plot_list <- lapply(plots_list, residual_plots)
```

Comment: Thank you so much your time and answer! Using the lapply() function has helped me plot them all on the same page!